# Localizing strings with variable integer in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to localize the string "I love the number x" where x is an integer.
So I have 2 questions, how do I do that in localizedStringForKey and what is the key value pair in my Localization.strings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I localize a string with formatting placeholders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881628/how-do-i-localize-a-string-with-formatting-placeholders)

Comment: I see no mention of .string file

Comment: Also I'm asking for swift.

Comment: `NSLocalizedString()` calls `localizedStringForKey`. You're looking for placeholders, and you can use `stringWithFormat:`. Functions that do the same in Objective-C or in Swift, no?

Comment: Then what should my key/value be in my localisation.strings

Comment: key: whatever you want, value "I love the number %d", then `var str = String.stringwithformat("NSLocalizedString("myKey", comment:""), myInt)`, or something like that (I don't speak Swift).