# iOS String Format with unknown parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app will be used in different countries, so we get localization parameters from API. For strings which have not got any parameters like `%@, %d` etc, there is no problem. But I cannot find any solution for a string with parameters.

For instance, is the service give me string like

```
"Your entered email must be at least %d character and maximum %d character" or it will have %@ parameters.
```

On a client, I know the giving parameters number because ı know its usage label or text field but cannot do any algorithm like String with format method.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:[string from service metod],%d,%d]; ---- xcode gives error for %d..
```

Comment: Give a real example of what you are trying to achieve, ur code is just plain wrong and I cannot understand what you need

Comment: Ok. For example the method is mine service Utils methos and it gives me a string value of the key. "[[MMMUtility sharedManager] getValueByKey:email_error]" ----- From the service,  email_error:"Lütfen e-posta adresinizi en az %d ve en fazla %d karakter olarak giriniz.". I know the value of key contains 2 parameters. But I cannot write like that -------NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat"[[MMMUtility sharedManager] getValueByKey:email_error], var1,var2];--- Can I explain? @Tj3n

Comment: this may be [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881628/how-do-i-localize-a-string-with-formatting-placeholders)

Comment: The code you show in the question itself gives an error as `%d` is not a valid expression (it only has meaning as part of a format string). However the code you show in your comment, apart from the minor typo (" instead of :), is in the correct form. You say this gives an error but do not say *what* error. Edit your question to include both the code in the comment and the error you get and that will probably enable someone to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string from service method %d %d", var1,var2];
```

Comment: :) I know this code also. But I dont have any static string. It is given me by service.

Comment: so, you can use [[MMMUtility sharedManager] getValueByKey:email_error] instead of var.

Comment: But the method gives error when I write ---------NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:[[MMMUtility sharedManager] getValueByKey:email_error], var1,var2];---- because Xcode can not put var1 and var2 for anything.

Comment: @BegümKırkgözDemirci Why error with this? You just need to make `int var1` without value and compiler will stop saying error?

Comment: First of all, your question was not clear. 
So, if you have a string with two numbers, then parse this two number from the string. If you still face any problem, let me know.