# How to localize stringWithFormat with %d?

Tags: ios, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have to localize detail-text-label using stringWithFormat with an integer value as shown below.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Remaining: %d", count];
```

Comment: will you please make it more clear what you are trying to do...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, assuming that `"Remaining: %d" = "Remaining: %d` is in your English Localizable.strings file and `"Remaining: %d" = "Restante: %d` is in your Spanish one, the following code will solve your particular problem:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Remaining: %d", @"description for translators"), count];
```

If you ever need to localize a string with more than one argument, then the above solution is not flexible enough (in some languages you may need to change the order of the placeholders). You can use [positional specifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063843/is-there-a-way-to-specify-argument-position-index-in-nsstring-stringwithformat) to add this kind of flexibility to your solution.