# How to merge loc-args with loc-key string in iOS Push notification

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I want to set the second element of the loc-args array from the push notification payload into the loc-key translation when my app is open, e.g. in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method.

Example of the loc-args in the payload is an array of two elements:

```
[
    "Apple",
    "1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 95014"
]
```

The translation for the loc-key is:

`Goto address: %2$@`

If the push message arrives when the app is in the background it works fine. The message is showed as:

`Goto address: 1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 95014`

But if the app is in the foreground I have to handle it by myself in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method for example with:

```
let message = String(format: "Goto address: %2$@",
                     arguments: ["Apple", "1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 95014"])
```

But this gives the result: `Goto address: Apple` instead of `Goto address: 1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 95014`

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Extra info:

If I change the loc-key to: `Goto address: %2$@ - %1$@` the text will be: `Goto address: 1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 95014 - Apple`

Thanks.

Comment: `String(format:...)` does not allow to *omit* a positional parameter. See for example the comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063843/is-there-a-way-to-specify-argument-position-index-in-nsstring-stringwithformat .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until a better solution I doing the following for loop:

```
//grab the loc key
var messageText = NSLocalizedString(locKey, comment: "Key for the alert message")

//we need to merge the loc-args into the currentText
if let locArgs:NSArray = alert["loc-args"] as? NSArray {
    for (index, _) in locArgs.enumerate() {
        messageText = messageText.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%\(index+1)$@", withString: locArgs[index] as! String)
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept your own answer if this solve the problem (it solved mine :) )

Answer (score 0):

you only have one "@" so string only get "apple".i think the position will work when both are gotten

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a fork from your Swift code to Obj-C

```
NSString *message = NSLocalizedString(locKey);
NSString *format = @"";
for (int i=0; i<[args count]; i++) {
    format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%d$@", i+1];
    message = [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:format withString:args[i]];
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? some people will need the code in Obj-C, this could be usefull for people